# Relative clauses: integrated, restrictive, non-restrictive, supplementary

Tags: relative-clauses

H. W. Fowler established a terminology (I do not know if it originates with him), where clauses that are related to another clause through a pronoun are called *relative clauses*; he further drew a distinction between *restrictive* and *non-restrictive* relative clauses to explain his famous rule about when to apply that vs. which.

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* rejects this terminology in favour of another terminology:

- Instead of restrictive relative clause, the *CGEL* prefers *integrated relative clause*;
- Instead of non-restrictive relative clause, the *CGEL* (always?, usually?) prefers *supplementary relative clause*.

Why does the CGEL, reflecting the preference in Anglistics, follow this alternative terminology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The authors themselves say of the traditional terms:

> They are misleading: the integrated relative is NOT always
>   restrictive, in the sense of picking out a subset of the set denoted
>   by the head noun.

They go on to give supporting examples. However, if you’re familiar with the CGEL, you probably already know this.

Comment: I've no current access to the CGEL, so thank you for looking this up.  Would you know if all non-restrictive rel. clauses are supplementary?

Comment: @CharlesStewart: It would seem so. I have only the stripped down version, 'A Student's Introduction to English Grammar'. That's why I began my answer with 'The authors . . .'

Comment: Ah, indeed thanks, I had forgotten about the existence of that book.  It is a bit cheaper than the full CGEL.